# Exported animated gif with matrices will not work?

Tags: matrix, export, bugs, animation, version-7

I want to export a list of matrices as a gif so that they will appear one after another 2 seconds apart. I've tried the following but when I open it up it only does the first two matrices and I have 10 altogether.

```
list = MatrixForm /@ {{{0.3333, 0, 0}, {0, 0.3333, 0}, {0, 0,0.3333}}, {{0.04466, 0, 0}, {0, 0.3333, 0}, {0, 0, 0.622}}, {{0.05954, 0, 0}, {0, 0.8293, 0}, {0, 0,0.1111}}, {{0.1163, 0, 0}, {0, 0.8681, 0}, {0, 0,0.01558}}, {{0.01707, 0, 0}, {0, 0.9511, 0}, {0, 0, 0.03185}}, {{0.01707, 0, 0}, {0, 0.9511, 0}, {0, 0, 0.03185}}, {{0.001264, 0, 0}, {0, 0.9811, 0}, {0, 0, 0.01761}}, {{0.0006892, 0, 0}, {0, 0.998, 0}, {0, 0, 0.001286}}, {{0.0006901, 0, 0}, {0, 0.9993, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}};

Export["N://presentation28.gif", list, "DisplayDurations" -> 3]
```

Comment: It is working ok on Win7 V9.0.1.0.

Comment: Im using it on the university desktop and not sure what they run.

Comment: Try `$Version`.

Comment: Sorry what does that mean?

Comment: windows 7.0. Ive tried it and it still doesnt work

Comment: What version are you using?  I can confirm the problem you describe using version 7 under Windows 7.

Comment: 7.0 mathematica on windows 7

Answer (score 7):

It appears that `Export` to `"GIF"` in *Mathematica* 7 fails (with a corrupt file) if the image frames (source elements) are not all the same size.  I'm surprised I don't remember this problem, but then again I don't remember a lot of things these days.  Anyway, a hackish solution for now:

```
bbox = MapThread[Max, Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"] & /@ list];

list2 = ImageCrop[Rasterize[#], bbox, Padding -> White] & /@ list;

Export["A://zod.gif", list2, "DisplayDurations" -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: @user32462 Glad I could help! :-)  Please consider Accepting this answer after a while, unless someone posts a better one.